# SELECT TOP N records by column value

Tags: mysql

For instance, in table id/article/view_counter I would like to select top 5 articles by view_counter.

I could SELECT *, order by view count and then take only first 5 when I loop through array but is there a way to do that directly in query?

Comment: Learn about `limit` and `order by`.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY view_count LIMIT 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to limit your records

```
SELECT ID, Article, count(view_counter) from table group by 1,2 order by 3 limit 5
```

Not sure your table structure, if view_Counter is already aggregate, you would just take the count and the group by off...

```
SELECT * from table order by 3 limit 5
```

This is assuming the view counter is your third column

If not then you would use

```
SELECT * from table order by view_counter limit 5
```

Comment: Yes, my concern was if this is effective if table is large since select * must go through entire table. But there is no other way right?

Comment: Select only the columns you need then. ID, Article, and View Counter should do it...actually Article and View Counter should be all you really need, but ID you can identify who it is I suppose...